# Blob are created but dont show the video

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying create a blob lik to use on my `<video>` but when the code apper in the SRC the video dont play. I dont know why, but my script until now is this below

```
<script>
var URL = this.window.URL || this.window.webkitURL;
var file = new Blob(["https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"],{"type" : "video\/mp4"});
    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
</script>
```

What's wrong in the script?

Comment: Have a look at the video element through your browser's dev tools - the src has just a few bytes. You have not waited for the video to load. You may also run up against a CORS problem. Do you need to create a blob rather than just use the URL in the video src? The system will have to wait for the entire video to load before doing the conversion - not very nice for the user if it's a long video.

Comment: I could even put the normal url, but I want to use the blob to hide it, like youtube, facebook does. Like what I'm trying to do. And the problems I am facing are the video when the big one does not load as it should. How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you trying to create the blob in advance (so the user doesnt have to wait, and moreover you don't need to put the url in the source code for the user to uncover)?

Comment: Yes that's what i'm trying to do, hide the link

Comment: I found that the blob also supports only 500 MB files, and my files are bigger than that

Answer (score 0):

The `src` attribute specifies the location of the video.
So your code should be

```
video.src = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4";
```

Another problem is that I don't see where you define the `video` variable

Comment: the variable video is the tag at the html. i don't created a variable, should i create one?

Comment: but in this case the original url appear on the src, and i need the blob like youtube and facebook does with their videos

Answer (score 0):

I found this question since I was having a similar problem. I'm using a `<video>` tag along with the [videojs](https://docs.videojs.com/) library, and retrieving the videos using blob.

The main problem I was having was that all blob requests were being completed successfully, but not all videos were being displayed like they should. Some were ok, but other videos would be just pitch black (the player would show the controls and autoplay the video normally, but it would show all black). Also, they were all being correctly set as `videoType: 'video/mp4'` since they were all .mp4.

After comparing the videos, I found out that the videos being correctly displayed all had **H.264** codecs, whilst the videos that weren't being displayed had **H.265** codecs.

I used a random online tool to convert one of the bad videos choosing the **H.264** codec as output, uploaded the converted video to my storage, and it fixed the problem. Only thing about converting videos online is that it will most likely come out with a poor video quality, so I'd recommend rendering the original video again with the correct codec, if possible.

Hope it helps somebody out there.